# cleanup C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\PendingDeletes and PendingRenames

Tags: windows-8, temporary-files, disk-cleanup, winsxs

Both, the PendingDeletes and the PendingRenames folder within the windows temp folder are about 1GB in size. Is there any save way to empty or delete those folders?

C:\Windows\WinSxS >10GB
C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\PendingDeletes 800MB
C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\PendingRenames 210MB

I have no pending installation. My operating system is Windows8.1 Is there any way to cleanup the WinSxS folder as a whole? I already used the clean-up utility when right clicking the disk. But did not change much!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean "shouldn't"? Overall there is no logical explanation why a plain Windows installation that is not use that much, consumes more than 20GB on the disk.

Comment: Use disk cleanup to remove windows updates and service pack backup files, this will reduce WinSxS quite a bit. It is the Only safe way to reduce WinSxS folder

Comment: WinSxS is a touchy folder. You can easily brick your system if you are not careful.

Comment: @moab. as I said, I used that cleanup tool already. Did not change much.

Comment: That's all you can do safely.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The safe way to clean up WinSxS is with Windows' [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825236.aspx). [Running the following in an elevated CMD prompt *should theoretically* remove some of the excess baggage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251565.aspx):

> DISM /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup

However, for that task to complete, *TrustedInstaller* must be running, which *is not set up in Windows 8 by default*. To run *TrustedInstaller*, you may need to first [enable *TelnetServer*](http://woshub.com/how-to-clean-up-and-compress-winsxs-folder-in-windows-8/), then enter

> net start TrustedInstaller

After DISM runs successfully (on my PC, I found that DISM worked only when Windows was started in Safe Mode), you may want to *disable* *TelnetServer* and stop TrustedInstaller.

After all this folderol, you may find only a modest reduction in the size of WinSxS. In my case, it was reduced from ~10 GB to ~7 GB. sigh.

[It is a great deal easier to use *Janitor* to clean up old Linux installations and updates, aka "cruff", but Windows is not Linux.]